# Convert string array into object Id array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of string

```
let stringObjectIdArray = ['fssdlfsd343','43434234242','342424242']
```

and I want to change the string array into an object Id array by using mongoose type but it didn't work. It only works for a string not array type.

```
let objectIdArray = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(stringObjectIdArray)
// above will give error
```

Is there a way to help me in this case? Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to invoke the method on every element of the array and collect the results into a new array:

```
const objectIdArray = stringObjectIdArray.map(s => new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(s));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: better add "new" before the ObjectId class

Comment: @drizzt13 Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simplify the accepted answer like this :

```
let objectIdArray = stringObjectIdArray.map(mongoose.Types.ObjectId);
```

Comment: depends on the node version and configuration, you might get this error:
`TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'`