# Convert array in string to an ObjectId in node/express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

I pass ids in a post request in postman and reference to another model and get

```
5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801, 5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808, 5dcf8c8fef739a6159938ca8
```

in my controller I convert them as

```
let ids = [req.body.ids]
console.log(ids)
```

and get

```
['5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801, 5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808, 5dcf8c8fef739a6159938ca8']
```

I wanted to convert them to an ObjectId so I tried

```
ObjectId(numberArray)
```

and

```
numberArray.map(num => ObjectId(num))
```

but all return

```
(node:25080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980042/convert-string-array-into-object-id-array

Comment: I also look to others and pass on that link too

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I mean someone suggest me to use split that returns a new array

```
let singers = ['5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801, 5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808, 5dcf8c8fef739a6159938ca8']
let singerArr = singers.split(', ')
console.log(singerArr);
```

```
[ '5dcf8c8fef739a6159938ca8',
  '5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801',
  '5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808' ]
```

and use for loop and find query to match to these ids and use mongoose.Types.ObjectId

though I'm having a different scenario to fix right now